# PHP отправка письма: сбой отправки

Tags: php

Подскажите, кто сталкивался.

Отправка письма функцией `mail()`.

При условии, когда пользователь заполняет адрес электронной почты и его адрес начинается с буквы p**@mail.com, то происходит сбой при вставке адреса в почтовом заголовке `From`. Начинается обработка его как тег `<p>` и соответственно письмо не уходит(

Как его кодировать или что настраивать?

```
 $headers = "From: \"От \" <p**@mail.com>\r\n".
          "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" .
          "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";

mail(MY_MAIL, $title, $message, $headers)
```

Comment: `$headers = "From: p**@mail.com\r\n". ...` ?

Comment: Так работает, но хотелось бы, чтоб был красивый заголовок в входящих

Comment: Экранирование не помогает ?

Comment: А вы красивый текст не хотите из UTF-8 перекодировать в base64 чтобы все было правильно?

Comment: Это что-то типа mb_encode_mimeheader ? (на что-то такое наткнулся)

Comment: Вот пример есть http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mail.php#108669

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте сменить кавычки на апострофы:

```
 $headers = 'From: "От " <p**@mail.com>\r\n' .
          'MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n' .
          'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n';
```